# com.facebook.FacebookGraphObjectException: Factory can't proxy method: public abstract void com.facebook.model.GraphUser.setBirthday()

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been editing the FriendPikcerSample provided by Facebook SDK for Android (latest version).

A couple of hours ago I successfully inserted a listview instead of a textview, so that when I select a name in the ListView, I can fetch more details of the user in the further activity

But Now, after restarting my PC, the app is behaving weird. When I launch it and click on "Pick Friends", it should be showing the list of friends who are using the app. Instead, now the app crashes and logcat shows this error.

```
12-30 07:35:15.820    2238-2238/com.facebook.samples.friendpicker E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.facebook.samples.friendpicker, PID: 2238
    com.facebook.FacebookGraphObjectException: Factory can't proxy method: public abstract void com.facebook.model.GraphUser.setBirthday()
            at com.facebook.model.GraphObject$Factory.verifyCanProxyClass(GraphObject.java:290)
            at com.facebook.model.GraphObject$Factory.createGraphObjectProxy(GraphObject.java:216)
            at com.facebook.model.GraphObject$Factory.coerceValueToExpectedType(GraphObject.java:340)
            at com.facebook.model.GraphObject$Factory$GraphObjectListImpl.get(GraphObject.java:772)
            at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:55)
            at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArrayList(AbstractCollection.java:349)
            at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:339)
            at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:188)
            at com.facebook.widget.SimpleGraphObjectCursor.addGraphObjects(SimpleGraphObjectCursor.java:46)
            at com.facebook.widget.GraphObjectPagingLoader.addResults(GraphObjectPagingLoader.java:203)
            at com.facebook.widget.GraphObjectPagingLoader.requestCompleted(GraphObjectPagingLoader.java:186)
            at com.facebook.widget.GraphObjectPagingLoader.access$000(GraphObjectPagingLoader.java:27)
            at com.facebook.widget.GraphObjectPagingLoader$2.onCompleted(GraphObjectPagingLoader.java:134)
            at com.facebook.Request$4.run(Request.java:1666)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone help me understand what's gone wrong?

Comment: This is weird, did you modify the GraphUser class at all? What version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: I don't remember opening & modifying the GraphUser class. Anyway, I deleted the entire SDK, and imported a fresh & untouched copy of it and then inserted my code in it. It all works fine now. I guess I'll never know the solution to this error for all the good.